# I want to use android-circlebutton library in my eclipse project

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle

I would like to know how can I use this great [library](https://github.com/markushi/android-circlebutton/) in my eclipse project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I f you know how to use gradle follow its instruction else try this way :

1. Download zip file and unzip it
2. Copy `android-circlebutton/library/src/main/java/at/markushi/ui/ CircleButton.java` to the `/src/your_project_package/` folder
3. open `CircleButton.java` and change the package in first line to your app package name and check the other error in file if there is and solve them .
4. Copy all file in `res/value` to your `/res/value` of your project , if you have same file open the file in library and copy the content into same file in your project !

**Its not a good approach but will resolve your problem !**

Comment: thank you...let me give a try